# What's the difference between /dev/dsk and /dev/sda?

Tags: filesystems

I was researching about block devices and character devices. I found an article that mentions how block devices are assigned as `/dev/sd[a-z]`. But then I read a different article that mentions how block devices are assigned as `/dev/dsk/[c#t#d#]`. Are they not both block devices? When is one used over the other?

Comment: It would be helpful if you would share the article where you found the nominations.

Comment: You can check if it is a block device by executing `file /dev/dsk/*`

Comment: Also it would be nice if you explain which OS you are thinking of.  /dev/sdX hints at Linux, but I can't remember seeing /dev/dsk there, usually there is /dev/disk. On the other hand, HP-UX has /dev/dsk/cXtYdZ, but no /dev/sdX. Maybe you mixed two different articles about two different systems?

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/sd[a-z]` is the most common naming scheme for hard disks in Linux.

Other Unix flavours use different naming schemes, you can find `/dev/dsk/` for example in HPUX or [Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/805-6331/6j5vgg680/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Some naming conventions are the result of how the **kernel discovers devices**, the first SCSI/SATA/SAS Disk gets the name `sda` allocated and the second `scb` and subsequent letters fo the alphabet are used for other disks.

Other device drives use different block device naming schemes for the devices they detect.

The ***problem with discovery*** is that discovery can fail, for example your first disk fails and then the second disk can get the name `sda` allocated, while before it was named `sdb`.  An `/etc/fstab` entry for sdb1 won't work anymore, but the data isn't gone, but now `sda1` needs to be mounted on that mount point.

To counter that ***persistent device naming*** schemes have been created, which can be used to identify a device correctly, even when discovery assigns it a different name. That are for example the `/dev/disk/by-uuid/*` and/or `/dev/disk/by-label/*` device names.

Some more background here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/managing_storage_devices/assembly_overview-of-persistent-naming-attributes_managing-storage-devices